# How to install Job Manager for WAS Liberty on Linux?

Tags: websphere

I am trying to install 'Job Manager' for WAS Liberty

Where can I find docs to install 'Job Manager' for WAS LIBERTY profile

Please let me know if any of you are already aware of

Comment: Are you trying to register a Liberty profile server with a full profile job manager, or are you looking for a job manager that runs on a Liberty profile server?  The latter does not exist as far as I know.

Comment: I am looking for a 'Job manager' that can run on Liberty profile server because I have not installed 'WAS Full profile'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM does not currently offer a Job Manager that runs on the Liberty profile.